# Google Sign in Error from IOS

Tags: ios, authentication, google-api, google-oauth

I get the following error trying to authnticate:
{error : "unauthorized_client"}

I get this error for a small percentage of users. I tested it with two different users on the same device and i was able to sign in with one but not the other. So it is something to do with the account not the device.

After sending the request the sign in process hangs during the "Wait please..." screen.

After it happens once, i need to remove the app and reinstall to be able to get to the sign in screen again.

Any ideas?

```
#import "Define.h"
#import "TIGoogleOAuthViewController.h"
#import "TIWebClient.h"
#import "TIAppDelegate.h"

@interface TIGoogleOAuthViewController ()
{
    User * _googleUserInfo;
}

@end

@implementation TIGoogleOAuthViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _googleUserInfo = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    self.googleOAuth = [[GoogleOAuth alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.googleOAuth setGOAuthDelegate:self];
    [self.googleOAuth authorizeUserWithClienID:kGoogleClientID
                           andClientSecret:kGoogleClientSecKEY
                             andParentView:self.view
                                 andScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
                                            @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", nil]
     ];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Google OAuth delegate

#pragma mark GoogleOAuth Delegate
-(void)authorizationWasSuccessful
{
    [self.googleOAuth callAPI:@"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
           withHttpMethod:httpMethod_GET
       postParameterNames:nil postParameterValues:nil];
}

-(void)accessTokenWasRevoked
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    message:@"Your access was revoked!"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
}

-(void)errorOccuredWithShortDescription:(NSString *)errorShortDescription andErrorDetails:(NSString *)errorDetails
{
    NSLog(@"%@", errorShortDescription);
    NSLog(@"%@", errorDetails);
}

-(void)errorInResponseWithBody:(NSString *)errorMessage
{
    NSLog(@"%@", errorMessage);
}

-(void)responseFromServiceWasReceived:(NSString *)responseJSONAsString andResponseJSONAsData:(NSData *)responseJSONAsData
                    access_token_file:(NSString*)access_token_file refresh_token_file:(NSString*)refresh_token_file
{

    if ([responseJSONAsString rangeOfString:@"family_name"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseJSONAsData
                                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                     error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"An error occured while converting JSON data to dictionary.");
            return;
        } else
        {
            NSLog(@"google responde = %@", dic);

            _googleUserInfo = [[User alloc] init];

            _googleUserInfo.email = [dic objectForKey:@"email"];
            _googleUserInfo.firstname = [dic objectForKey:@"given_name"];
            _googleUserInfo.lastname = [dic objectForKey:@"family_name"];
            _googleUserInfo.image_profile = [dic objectForKey:@"picture"];

            NSMutableDictionary * tokenDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:access_token_file];
            _googleUserInfo.google_access_token = [tokenDic objectForKey:@"access_token"];

            //save to permanent storage
            NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [pref setValue:access_token_file forKey:@"access_token_file"];
            [pref setValue:refresh_token_file forKey:@"refresh_token_file"];
            [pref synchronize];

            //notify to web server
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^(void)
                           {
                               [[TIWebClient getInstance] googleSignIn:_googleUserInfo andDelegate:self];

                           });
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Login delegate
-(void) didLoginFailed
{
    NSLog(@"Google Login failed");
}

-(void) didLoginSuccess:(User *)user type:(NSInteger)type
{
    TIAppDelegate * app = (TIAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [DataManager dataManager].mine = user;
    [DataManager putPreference:YES :[DataManager dataManager].mine];

    [app showMainView:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: unauthorized_client normally has something to do with using a refreshtoken with a different client id then it was created for.  you will need to post some code before anyone can help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What part of the code? the URL sent to Google?